# C++ TensorFlow SoftmaxCrossEntropWithLogits returns (cost, gradients), how to access cost?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a simple neural network in C++ TensorFlow.

I am unable to access loss returned by SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits).

Please check the "Returns" segment in above mentioned link. I want to access only "loss" output. I am unable to write this in C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here it doesn't return anything, its an attribute. You can access it from the class instance.

```
#define the loss class instance with your logits and labels
softmax_loss_function = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits(const ::tensorflow::Scope & scope, ::tensorflow::Input features, ::tensorflow::Input labels) 
# access the loss
loss = softmax_loss_function.loss
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one doubt. It is mentioned on official page of this function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits) that it calculates cross entropy and gradients and returns them also. So, I am confused..

Comment: there's another attribute `backprop` to access the computed gradients.

Comment: So do you mean to say that this function will not return any value (loss and gradients) until I'll define it? Because when I am doing softmax_loss_function.loss, I am getting error in C++: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = tensorflow::Output]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)

Comment: it will return `tensor`, might be you are not defining inputs properly.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. I'll try again. Although I am sure about correctness of inputs. Thanks a lot.. :-)